# Jboss, Eclipse, JavaEE, JPA

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb, jboss7.x, war

I am trying to develope Java EE application in Eclipse IDE. I am using JBoss 7.0 app server.

My project contains 3 containers:

**EAR**:

-EJB (EJB 3.0 - business logic)

-JPA (JPA 2.0 - EclipseLink 2.3.x, entities from database, data access object layer)

-WAR (JSF 2.0 - managed beans and .xhtml pages)

**App logic**:

- My JPA container manipulates with the database and perform basic CRUD operations.
- EJB container is using the JPA's methods in order to communicate with the WAR (managed beans).
- WAR perform the user requests and communicate with the EJB container in order to get required result from the database for specific user.

**Problem that costs me too much time and still no solution:**

I've configured those 3 containers to work together properly with test methods (only containing strings) but I am facing an issue when **trying to inject @EJB SessionBean to WAR (managed bean) after setting up the real methods that actually returns something from DB**.

```
HTTP STATUS 400: The requested resources is unavailable.
```

This is my JPA's DAO class where I am not pretty sure wheather I've instantiated the entitymanager and entity manager factory correctly (Should I use @PersistanceContext(unitName="testing-jpa") instead?):

```
public class TestDAOImpl implements ITestDAO {

    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("testing-jpa");
    EntityManager manager = emf.createEntityManager();
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

    @Override
    public List<User> getList() {
        users = manager.createNamedQuery("User.findAll", User.class).getResultList();
        return users;
    }

}
```

OK. So the method **getList()** performs the query for User entity. This method is called in the EJB container. The EJB's TestStateless class that implements **Remote** interface:

```
@Stateless(mappedName = "testStateless")
public class TestStateless implements TestStatelessLocal {

    public TestStateless() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public String getText() {
        return "hello from ejb3";
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        ITestDAO testDao = new TestDAOImpl();
        return testDao.getList();
    }

}
```

**Now, after I've defined EJB's TestStateless.getUsers() method I got 404 STATUS**.

This is how my WAR's ManagedBean class looks like:

```
public class ManageBean {

    @EJB
    TestStatelessRemote testBean;

    public ManageBean() {

    }

    public String getSomeText() {
        return "" + 123;
    }

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return testBean.getUsers();
    }

}
```

After this point, I should use ManagedBean's getUsers() method on .xhtml page and loop through the dataTable in order to list each user on the page.

This is my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="testing-jpa" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS</non-jta-data-source>
        <class>com.model.User</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cs450_pr"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Update:**

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
  <display-name>testing-war</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**Console log:**

```
16:44:04,699 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.0.1.GA
16:44:05,027 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.0.GA
16:44:05,105 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBoss AS 7.0.1.Final "Zap" starting
16:44:06,125 WARN  [org.jboss.as] No security realm defined for native management service, all access will be unrestricted.
16:44:06,137 INFO  [org.jboss.as] creating http management service using network interface (management) port (9990)
16:44:06,140 WARN  [org.jboss.as] No security realm defined for http management service, all access will be unrestricted.
16:44:06,155 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] Removing bootstrap log handlers
16:44:06,191 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (Controller Boot Thread) Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
16:44:06,212 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan.subsystem] (Controller Boot Thread) Activating Infinispan subsystem.
16:44:06,486 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (Controller Boot Thread) Activating Naming Subsystem
16:44:06,508 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-3) Starting Naming Service 
16:44:06,512 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (Controller Boot Thread) Activating OSGi Subsystem
16:44:06,592 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (Controller Boot Thread) Activating Security Subsystem
16:44:06,604 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBoss Remoting version 3.2.0.Beta2
16:44:06,627 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-7) XNIO Version 3.0.0.Beta3
16:44:06,671 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-7) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.0.Beta3
16:44:07,123 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener] (MSC service thread 1-3) The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;native;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\msys\1.0\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;.
16:44:07,140 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ee] (Controller Boot Thread) Activating EE subsystem
16:44:07,709 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jmx.JMXConnectorService] (MSC service thread 1-3) Starting remote JMX connector
16:44:07,801 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-7) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http--127.0.0.1-8080
16:44:07,929 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-3) Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.3.Final)
16:44:08,035 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-3) Bound data source [java:/miksijevJNDI]
16:44:08,074 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-1) Listening on /127.0.0.1:9999
16:44:08,204 INFO  [org.jboss.as.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\Users\Milan\jboss-as-7.0.1.Final\standalone\deployments
16:44:08,251 INFO  [org.jboss.as.deployment] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) Found testing-ear.ear in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called testing-ear.ear.dodeploy
16:44:08,286 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBoss AS 7.0.1.Final "Zap" started in 4056ms - Started 93 of 148 services (55 services are passive or on-demand)
```

Comment: How much is the advance payment?

Comment: Let's get serious! ;-) I spent too much time searching for answer and still nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: All the codes you have posted is not really relevant for the error you are getting `HTTP 404`. You get this error because you type an url in your browser for a certain resource and the app server cannot find it, that's where you should focus your trouble shooting. Your managed bean is not annotated with `@ManagedBean` and you haven't shown your `web.xml` and you haven't shown the url you use to do the request. Please add those informations to your question. And I still want to know about advance payment, and I am serious!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I mentioned, I've configured everything and it worked properly before I tryed to replace the test methods with the real stuff. I am accessing on _http://localhost:8080/testing-war/_.

**Note:** that I can access to my index.xhtml normally when I make @EJB injection a comment in my managedbean.

Comment: Post is updated, btw.

Comment: did you check the logs of your app server for any exceptions?

Comment: I've provided a console log in the post. I've noticed that the last line of log is about some failure: _Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed.._ Could this be a problem since it's throwing me an HTTP 404.

Comment: The logs says that the context is not started, this explains 404 HTTP status code. Also you log complains about a `TestStateless`**`Remote`** but you bean only implements **Local**. Try to change `ManageBean` to have `@EJB TestStatelessLocal testBean;`

Comment: I did (_console log is updated_). I dont even know what keywords to use in order to google about it.. I've been developing java ee applications in NetBeans but not in Eclipse, it's confusing.